# Disabling switching to years view in Bootstrap datetimepicker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap's datetime picker from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. I want to disable switching to years view mode, and group of years view mode when clicking on name of the month in Bootstrap datetimepicker. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Set the [viewMode](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#maxviewmode).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set full dates and still be able to switch to month view, you need to set the `maxViewMode` like so:

```js
$('#pick').datepicker({
  maxViewMode: 'months'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<input type="text" id="pick">
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap datetimepicker.js from the link above, it's an modified version, and your suggestion doesn't function.